# conditions case not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, acts-as-taggable-on

i use acts-as-taggable-on for tagging.

apartments_controller

```
def index
  if params[:tag]
    @apartments = Apartment.tagged_with(params[:tag])
  else
    @apartments = Apartment.all
  end    
end
```

routes

```
resources :apartments do
  #...
  collection do
    get ':tag', to: 'apartments#index', as: :tag
  end
  #...
```

I get nice urls by example `/apartments/tag1` etc.

I want to show custom content based on the tag name in the apartments `index` template.

`Apartment`'s `index` view:

```
- @appartments.each do |tags|
   - case tags.tag_list
   - when "tag1"
      %p tag1 content
   - when "tag2"
      %p tag2 content
   - else
      %p default content
```

When i go to url `apartments/tag1` the text `"default content"` is show and not `"tag1 content"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `tags.tag_list`? You can do a `%p= tags.tag_list` before your case statement to see the output

Comment: when i go to a apartment with a tag1 in the console. a = Apartment.find(28) a.tag_list i get "tag1" as output

Comment: Try a to_s on the tag_list: `- case tags.tag_list.to_s`.

Answer (score 1):

There several notes about your code:

1. Keep your logic away from views. I.e. extract code into helper methods.
2. Do not use `case` on `Enumerable`, in your case it seems like an array. Use `include?` to check whether element is present inside an array:

---

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > a= [:a, :b, :c]
 => [:a, :b, :c] 
1.9.3p194 :002 > case a
1.9.3p194 :003?>   when :a
1.9.3p194 :004?>   p '1'
1.9.3p194 :005?>   when :b
1.9.3p194 :006?>   p '2'
1.9.3p194 :007?>   when :c
1.9.3p194 :008?>   p '3'
1.9.3p194 :009?>   when :d
1.9.3p194 :010?>   p 'Never'
1.9.3p194 :011?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :012 > a.include?(:c)
 => true
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, like this by example...rails c > a = Apartment.find(26) > a.tag_list > output => ["lux", "familie", "groups"] and then a.include?("lux") i get this error NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' (ruby 1.9.2p290 / activemodel-3.2.8)

Comment: `a.tag_list.include?('lux')` Seems like there typo?